# Nested Firebase data for TableView

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having a little trouble accessing and saving nested Firebase data.

Here is how my database is set up:

[image: 1]

How would I get Bike and Popsicle into an array as well as getting country and price in 2 other arrays? I will be using these arrays to populate a TableView.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Test")
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
   if let data = snapshot.value as? [String : [String : NSNumber]] {
        let bikePopsicleArray = Array(data.keys)
        let countryArray = [String]()
        let pricesArray = [NSNumber]()
        for (key, value) in data.values {
            countryArray.append(key)
            pricesArray.append(value)
        }
   }
})
```

Not sure if this will work but give it a try, let me know how it goes.